# Get time difference without converting to epoch using tcl

Tags: tcl

I am using tcl to get time difference, however I am first converting the time to epoch then doing the difference.  Looking for how to do this without converting to epoch.

```
set t1 "00:00:11.026"
set t2 "00:00:11.028"

# this method fails
puts [expr $t2 - $t1]
```

so I convert to epoch then it works.

```
set rawDate "2022-01-01 [lindex [split $t1 "."] 0]"
set t1 [expr [clock scan $rawDate -format {%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S} -gmt 1]\
+ ".[lindex [split $t1 "."] 1]"]

set rawDate "2022-01-01 [lindex [split $t2 "."] 0]"
set t2 [expr [clock scan $rawDate -format {%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S} -gmt 1]\
+ ".[lindex [split $t2 "."] 1]"]

puts [expr $t1 - $t2]
```

Comment: That's likely the only way. Make a function for it if you want to hide the details.

Answer (score 2):

If your times are run times that you want to compare, rather than time stamps, then converting to epoch may sometimes produce unexpected results. In that case I would suggest to convert the times to milliseconds using a proc, possibly in the tcl::mathfunc namespace so you can use it within expr:

```
proc tcl::mathfunc::runtime {str} {
    if {[scan $str %d:%d:%d.%d hh mm ss mmm] != 4} {error "invalid time: $str"}
    return [expr {($hh * 3600 + $mm * 60 + $ss) * 1000 + $mmm}]
}

expr {runtime($t2) - runtime($t1)}; # => 2
```

Also, get into the habit to brace your expressions. Among other things, it will make them run quite a bit faster.